# How can I get corr in pandas dataframe on specified columns elegantly?

Tags: python, pandas

corr is a good function in pandas dataframe, but i may not want to calculate them all.

here is a example:

```
In [17]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.reshape(np.random.rand(25), (5,5)), columns = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'])

In [18]: df
Out[18]: 
          a         b         c         d         e
0  0.838749  0.320802  0.912720  0.282949  0.927854
1  0.023636  0.430230  0.204737  0.955598  0.791329
2  0.207512  0.004523  0.760046  0.879304  0.811682
3  0.787845  0.268755  0.912230  0.131329  0.999888
4  0.981292  0.867131  0.259114  0.796924  0.015595

In [19]: df.corr()
Out[19]: 
          a         b         c         d         e
a  1.000000  0.503521  0.285477 -0.631558 -0.364213
b  0.503521  1.000000 -0.676612  0.169081 -0.834762
c  0.285477 -0.676612  1.000000 -0.776287  0.680733
d -0.631558  0.169081 -0.776287  1.000000 -0.477167
e -0.364213 -0.834762  0.680733 -0.477167  1.000000
```

i only want corr between [a, b] and [c, d, e]

which means:

```
corr(a, c) corr(a, d) corr(a, e)

corr(b, c) corr(b, d) corr(b, e)
```

is what i want.

a simple idea is:

```
df[['a', 'b']].corr(df[['c', 'd', 'e']])
```

but it failed with error.

I can select what i want out, by finding them by index and columns.

but i think it's not very elegant, is there any ideas? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [corrwith](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.corrwith.html#pandas.DataFrame.corrwith), as follows:

```
res = df[['c', 'd', 'e']].apply(df[['a', 'b']].corrwith)
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
          c         d         e
a  0.410747 -0.503276  0.101129
b -0.595421  0.945503 -0.951547
```

Note that this may not seem more elegant but for a large number of columns should be faster than doing corr and indexing.